# sbt testOnly not working

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to run a single test class in a Java Play project but fails misserably.

If I try to run

> testOnly my.app.TheClassTest

from within sbt (as described in [JavaTest](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaTest) and [sbt test](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Testing.html)) I get this result:

> [info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
>
> [info] No tests to run for test:testOnly

My only suspicion is that the message "*No tests to run for test:testOnly*" does not include the name of the class I try to test.

If I try to run it from command line

> sbt testOnly "my.app.TheClassTest"

It runs all the tests and then I get the following error:

> [error] Expected ID character
>
> [error] Not a valid command: net (similar: set, new, inspect)
>
> [error] Expected project ID
>
> [error] Expected configuration
>
> [error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
>
> [error] Expected key
>
> [error] Not a valid key: my (similar: test, name, assets)
>
> [error] my.app.TheClassTest

I've tried all kinds of variations such as *testOnly TheClassTest*, *test-only my.app.TheClassTest*, *test:testOnly* etc. with only minor variations in result. Using *testOnly* within sbt I can write whatever I feel like and still always get the same response.

Running all tests work fine.

Is there at least a way to get a more

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From sbt you can try to get the autocompletion for the command:

```
sbt:my-project> testOnly <tab>
```

It should display the lists of tests classes that are available. This may not work with the oldest versions of sbt.

If you see no classes, try to run `test:compile` before to compile your test classes.

Comment: It turned out that I misunderstood the _my.app_ part. should have been just _v1.xxx_. I'm fairly new to Play/sbt and did not know there was an autocomplete. Thanks.

Comment: if you run from console and not from inside sbt, then don't forget to put the argument as a whole into "..", e.g. `$ sbt "testOnly myPackage.myTestClass"`, or if you want continues monitoring, then: `$ sbt "~testOnly myPackage.myTestClass"`

Comment: The answers previously given should fix it. Just as a note on the side for some viewers, do not say `"sbt testOnly *MyTest.scala"` It will not work if you specifiy the file type `.scala` and you will also receive `No tests run` message. Instead, `sbt testOnly *MyTest` will work.

Answer (score 16):

From sbt you can try to get the autocompletion for the command:

```
sbt:my-project> testOnly <tab>
```

When running from command line (so outside the sbt prompt), for example in continuous integration, or other scripts etc., then you take the command in quotes **including** **the** **argument**, like this:

```
sbt "testOnly my.package.TheClassTest"
```

Otherwise testOnly does not seem to receive the argument.

Comment: This catches me out. Every. Single. Time. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 1):

For sbt 1.5.2, this worked:

`sbt "project dbm; testOnly my.package.TestClass"`